# Why is my linked character losing its animation when I reopen the blend file?

Tags: animation, objects, linked-data

I currently have a lot of problems with linking objects.
I created a model with an armature etc. in File A and want to link the object to File B for animating it. I also created another File C for the asset the character is using.
So everything works fine, I can link character and asset to the new file and animate it. Then I save and close the file. After opening it again either the animation I created is missing and the character is in A-pose again or the asset is flying around somewhere in space and isn't at the right location. So in conclusion I have to animate everything again.

Does anyone knows what the problem is? I also tried to link the whole collection where the model is in, but that doesn't work either.

Comment: are you sure the animation was saved? If it was not used by an object, or if you didn't click on the F as Fake User, it won't be automatically saved and it will be lost when you reopen the file

Comment: Yes, I'm sure it was saved because I rendered it but in the rendered scene the asset was at the wrong position, but the animation was still there. So I reopened the file to check about the asset and then the animation was missing.